# maping over a list and taking the colmeans and rowmeans in r

Tags: r

I am trying to compute the column means and row means of some data I have.

Its similar to the following:

```
library(rsample)
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)

aapl <- tq_get("AAPL", start_date = "2000-01-01")
aapl_monthly_nested <- aapl %>%
  mutate(ym = yearmonth(date)) %>%
  nest(-ym)
aapl_rolled <- aapl_monthly_nested %>%
  rolling_origin(cumulative = FALSE)


map(aapl_rolled$splits, ~ analysis(.x)) %>%
  head
```

I try using the `summarise_all` function once I have mapped over the data but I cannot seem to get the `colMeans`. I have replaced `colMeans` with `mean` without luck.

```
x <- map(aapl_rolled$splits, ~analysis(.x), 
    ~map(data, 
         ~summarise_all(.funs(colMeans))))

x[[1]]$data
```

I would like a single observation of the column means for each of the splits.

EDIT:

I think I got it. - I believe I forgot the `unnest` the data after nesting it previously.

```
x <- map(aapl_rolled$splits, ~ analysis(.x) %>%
           unnest() %>%
           as_tibble(.) %>% 
           select(-year_month) %>% 
           summarise_all(mean))
```

If you have a better solution please let me know.

Comment: With `colMeans` you could do `map(aapl_rolled$splits, ~ analysis(.x) %>%
      unnest(data) %>%
      select(-ym, -date) %>% 
      colMeans)`